# Javascript no longer works after performing AJAX Post

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Good day. I have been using AJAX post for a while now. I have this javascript code that allows blocks of html codes to be collapsed / expanded when clicked (it is collapsed by default). It works when the form loads for the first time, but once I perform an AJAX post the javascript code doesn't work anymore. I've tried placing the javascript code in the place where the php functions are performed, but that doesn't work either.

I'm not really that well-versed with Javascript or AJAX and I only derived this code from an external source. Any help would be much appreciated.

Javascript:

```
   <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                        $('p.content2').hide(); 
                        $('p.content2').addClass('active').next().show(); 
                        $('button.clickThis').click(function()

            {
                 if( $(this).next().is(':hidden'))
                    { 
                        $('p.clickThis').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); 
                }               
            else
                {
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('slow');
                }
            return false;
            });
        }); 
</script>
```

AJAX Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTask()
{if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

var params = 'taskName='+encodeURI(document.getElementById('taskName').value)+'&taskDesc='+encodeURI(document.getElementById('taskDesc').value)+'&btnCreateTask='+encodeURI(document.getElementById('btnCreateTask').value);
xmlhttp.open("POST","taskProcess.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);}
</script>
```

Comment: If you will format your code with proper indentation, people will have an easier time reading it; and as a result, people will be more likely to help you.  You will also find that, if you make a habit of using proper indentation, you will be better able to locate and solve problems in your own code.

Comment: first check the error console.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that JavaScript execution is stopping due to an error?

Do you use FireFox?  Try the page with the FireBug plugin installed and activated, and watch the "Console" tab.  If there's a JavaScript error, you'll see it there.

(If you use Chrome, there are the Developer Tools built in, and recent versions of IE also have some developer tools available if you hit F12.  Personally I don't like either of them as much as FireBug.)

Comment: I tried checking with FireBug (great plugin, thanks for the suggestion) but it didn't find any errors.